# REGEX - Highlight part over 19 chars

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, contenteditable

**Hi,**

I have some text inside `div[contenteditable="true"]` and I should highlight (`span.tooLong`) part which goes over the 19 character limit. Content in `div` may have HTML tags or entities and those should be ignored when counting to 19.

Twitter has similar way to highlight too long tweet:

[image: Twitter's highlight]

**Examples:**

- `This is text` ⇨ `This is text`
- `This is just too long text` ⇨ `This is just too lo<span class="tooLong">ng text</span>`
- `This <b>text</b> has been <i>formatted</i> with HTML` ⇨ `This <b>text</b> has been <span class="tooLong"><i>formatted</i> with HTML</span>`

**How can I implement this in JavaScript?**

(I want to use regular expressions as much as possible)

Comment: The twitter "textbox" is not a classical input field but a set of divs, one for complete one for incomplete http://i.imgur.com/M6RQvct.png

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with *complete* and *incomplete* in this case?

Comment: Is *incomplete* text before highlighting .. or what?

Comment: valid and not valid is what I mean. You have to manually manage the input

Comment: **Manually** .. sounds bad

Comment: Its a lot easier if he doesnt need highlighting.. then he can just use two overlaid textboxs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay...  here's some code that I think will work for you, or at least get your started.

Basically, the regex you need to find everything over 19 characters is this:

```
var extra = content.match(/.{19}(.*)/)[1];
```

So, I put together a sample document of how you might use this.

Take a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OnAxULu/1)**.

Here's the Javascript I'm using (I'm using jQuery for the locators here, but this can easily be modified to use straight Javascript...  I just prefer jQuery for stuff like this)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').keyup(function() {
    var content = $('#myDiv').html();
    var extra = content.match(/.{19}(.*)/)[1];

    $('#extra').html(extra);

    var newContent = content.replace(extra, "<span class='highlight'>" + extra + "</span>");
    $('#sample').html(newContent);
  });
});
```

Basically, I have three DIVs setup.  One for you to enter your text.   One to show what characters are over the 19 character limit.   And one to show how you might highlight the extra characters.

My code sample does not check for html tags, as there are too many to try and handle...  but should give you a great starting point as to how this might work.

**NOTE**: you can view the complete code I wrote using this link:  http://jsbin.com/OnAxULu/1/edit

Comment: Good job! How can I highlight in #myDiv? I don't want to show sample in another div. This doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/OnAxULu/2/edit

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how to take it to that level.   That's why I kept the "demo" a bit more simple.   :D

Comment: @petjato Why thanks!!  I did not expect that... as I knew I wasn't able to answer your question 100%... but I was hoping to be able to get you on the right path :)

Comment: Yep, that's enough :P

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer that uses my Rangy library. It uses the [Class Applier](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) and [TextRange](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule) modules to apply styling on character ranges within the editable content while preserving the selection. It also uses a configurable [debounce](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) interval to prevent sluggishness in editor performance. Also, it should work on old IE.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/G4jn7/2/

Sample code:

```
var characterLimit = 40;
var debounceInterval = 200;

function highlightExcessCharacters() {
    // Bookmark selection so we can restore it later
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    var savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(editor);

    // Remove previous highlight
    var range = rangy.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(editor);
    classApplier.undoToRange(range);

    // Store the total number of characters
    var editorCharCount = range.text().length;

    // Create a range selecting the excess characters
    range.selectCharacters(editor, characterLimit, editorCharCount);

    // Highlight the excess
    classApplier.applyToRange(range);

    // Restore the selection
    sel.restoreCharacterRanges(editor, savedSel);
}

var handleEditorChangeEvent = (function() {
    var timer;

    function debouncer() {
        if (timer) {
            timer = null;
        }
        highlightExcessCharacters();
    }

    return function() {
        if (timer) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = window.setTimeout(debouncer, debounceInterval);
    };
})();

function listen(target, eventName, listener) {
    if (target.addEventListener) {
        target.addEventListener(eventName, listener, false);
    } else if (target.attachEvent) {
        target.attachEvent("on" + eventName, listener);
    }
}

rangy.init();
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var classApplier = rangy.createClassApplier("overrun");

// Set up debounced event handlers
var editEvents = ["input", "keydown", "keypress", "keyup",
                  "cut", "copy", "paste"];

for (var i = 0, eventName; eventName = editEvents[i++]; ) {
    listen(editor, eventName, handleEditorChangeEvent);
}
```

Comment: This answer actually lets the highlighting be applied to the input like twitter does, so imo is the better answer. (Also very useful Library)

Comment: ...and thanks for the link on debouncing - that was an interesting read.